# Why is double-finger scrolling smooth in some applications but in others not so much?

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

On my System76 laptop, I've noticed that the double scroll works great in some applications, and not so great in others.

For example, as far as web browsers go, the double finger scroll is smooth in Firefox, yet less smooth, even "jumpy" in Chrome.

Has anybody else noticed this and do they know the reason why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scrolling behaviour varies by each application because it relies on the app-specific implementation. In Chrome, for instance, you can activate experimental smooth scrolling support from the *flags* menu, which you can access by typing `chrome://flags/` in your address bar.